# Following-or-end in xslt/xpath?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

[*XPath Axes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes) contain the directive `following::` to obtain the set of all following nodes.

Given for instance the following file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
    <a/>
    <b/> <!-- access 1 -->
    <a/>
    <ca/>
    <a/>
    <b/>
    <a/>
    <a/>
    <cb/>
    <b/> <!-- access 2 -->
</foo>
```

One can for instance use `following::a/preceding::b[1]` to access `access 1` given `<ca>`. In other words one wish to access:

> the "last" `<b>` before the next `<a>`.

If the current node is however `<cb>`, that trick doesn't work anymore, since there is no `following::a`. Is there a *following-or-end* directive (or something equivalent) that in that case returns the last tag (`</foo>`), such that `access 2` can be obtained from `<cb/>`?

Such following-or-next should be read as:

> The next `<a>` or the end of the file in case this doesn't exist.

The requested behavior is thus:

```
+--------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------+
| context-node | required result | current result                          |
+--------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------+
| <ca>         | access 1        | access 1                                |
| <cb>         | access 2        | none (since following::a doesn't exist) |
+--------------+-----------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Equivalently, *preceding-or-start* should be useful.

Comment: I got a little confused when you mentioned `</foo>` tag to be returned. We should be considering elements and not individual start/end tags.. Can you post your expected output? I assume the context node is `cb`

Comment: @LingamurthyCS: the expected output is `access 2` (thus the last `<b>` tag), since this is the "first" preceding tag with `<b>`.

Comment: I don't think I get the question, but having `cb` as the context node, to access `b`, you can use `following::b`

Comment: @LingamurthyCS: true, but in that case, for `<ca>`, the result isn't `access 1` anymore. The requested result is *"the last `<b> before the next `<a>`, or use a virtual `<a>` as last node in case that `<a>` doesn't exist."*

Comment: @LingamurthyCS: indeed. One can of course use a more compilcated `xsl:if`, but that will probably introduce more computational effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find what you require using:

```
( following-sibling::a[1]/preceding-sibling::b[1] | ../b[last()] )[1]
```

The left hand argument of the union (`|`) operator will return the last-b-before-the-next-a (or an empty set if there is no `following-sibling::a`), and right hand argument will always return the *last* `b` sibling of the context node (regardless of whether or not that particular `b` has a following `a` sibling).  The overall `(...)[1]` will then select whichever of these is first in document order.

This works even if the last `b` is before the context node, e.g. given

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
    <a/>
    <b/> <!-- access 1 -->
    <a/>
    <ca/>
    <a/>
    <b/>
    <a/>
    <a/>
    <cb/>
    <b/> <!-- access 2 -->
    <cc/>
</foo>
```

this expression would still return "access 2" if `cc` is the context node.

Answer (score 1):

> One can for instance use `following::a/preceding::b[1]` to access `access 1` given `<ca>`.

No, this can select more than one node - it selects *any* `<b>` that precedes *any* following `<a>`.

---

> the "last" `<b>` before the next `<a>`.

That would be (I simply assume you actually mean `following-sibling`):

```
following-sibling::a[1]/preceding-sibling::b[1]
```

e.g.

```
<foo>
    <a/>
    <b/>
    <a/>   <!-- 3. preceding-sibling::b[1] - selected node -->
    <ca/>  <!-- 1. context node -->
    <a/>   <!-- 2. following-sibling::a[1] -->
    <b/>   
    <a/>   
    <a/>
    <cb/>
    <b/>
</foo>
```

and this would still select nothing when the context is at `<cb>`, so we change the expression to adapt.

```
(
    following-sibling::a[1]/preceding-sibling::b[1]
    |
    following-sibling::b[1]
)[1]
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `b[last()]`? In the second or-part (`|`)?

Comment: Hm I don't know. Should it? I assumed with "last `<b>` before the next `<a>`" you meant "the last preceding `<b>`", which would rather mean `[1]` in my opinion. (or I misunderstood the definition)

Comment: @CommuSoft Side note, `|` does not mean "or", it is the operator for "union" set operation, it creates a duplicate-free set of nodes in document order.

Comment: @CommuSoft To clarify whether `last()` or `1` is correct, you simply need to think what should happen if the document goes `<cb/><b/><b/>`.

Comment: thanks for the side notes. It indeed depends on the exact situation. And that doesn't have to be specified in the question. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> The next `<a>` or the end of the file in case this doesn't exist.

Given a **test input** of:

```
<foo>
    <a id="1"/>
    <b id="2" /> <!-- access 1 -->
    <a id="3"/>
    <ca/>
    <a id="4"/>
    <b id="5"/>
    <a id="6"/>
    <a id="7"/>
    <cb/>
    <b id="8"/> <!-- access 2 -->
</foo>
```

The following **XPath expression**:

```
(following::a[1] | following::*[last()])[1]
```

will select `<a id="4"/>` when evaluated from the context of `ca`, and `<b id="8"/>` when evaluated from the context of `cb`.

There's probably a better way to solve the *real* issue behind this abstract problem.